# How do I get the shell variable value in Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to pass some secrets to shell commands using environment variables. The Popen seems using "single quote concept" to escape the arguments so the commands cannot get the variable value.

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Mar  3 2017, 10:25:58) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo','$PATH'])
$PATH
```

Expected output is the real $PATH values like "/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin..."

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a shell to evaluate your line:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo $PATH', shell=True)
```

But if this is all you want then consider this:

```
print os.getenv('PATH')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `shell=True`, but be careful https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

```
subprocess.Popen('echo $PATH', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using shell is dangerous if the command line is filed from external sources, so use it with caution.

Also, there is an optional parameter to decide where the shell should be when launching the command.

```
command = 'echo $PATH'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, cwd='./')
p.communicate() # it would wait until the subprocess is complete.
```